# Magento 2 - error creating db table from custom schema

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create a custom module for Magento 2 and I've got to the point of defining the schema in the /Setup/InstallSchema.php

When running 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade' I get the error:
Call to undefined function Test/Connector/Setup/getConnection()

The module is enabled and correctly showing in the config file. The schema file I'm trying to run is:

```
<?php 
namespace Test\Connector\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{


public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface 
$context) {
  $installer = $setup;

  $installer->startSetup();

  $tableName = $installer->getTable('test_connector_settings');

  if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
     $table = $installer->getConnection()
      ->newTable($installer->getTable('ipos_connector_settings'))
      ->addColumn('id', Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, ['identity'=> true, 'nullable'=>false, 'primary'=>true], 'ID')
  ->addColumn('api_url', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable'=>true], 'API URL')
      ->addColumn('api_user', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 100, ['nullable'=>false], 'API User Name')
      ->addColumn('api_password', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 100, ['nullable'=>false], 'API Password');

     $installer-getConnection()->createTable($table);
  }

  $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line

```
$installer-getConnection()->createTable($table); // your code line.
```

With

```
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

Comment: Thank you Jitendra, although I do feel a little embarrassed now. I was so focused on the first two instances of getConnection() I never got as far as the third. Lesson learned, first step to solving a problem is use a validator!